# Cuda kernel seems to block, launch timed out and was terminated

Tags: cuda

i wrote a lib in CUDA that loads JPEG files and a viewer that displays them.
Both parts make heavy use of CUDA, the sources are on SourceForge:

cuview & cujpeg

I store an image as RGB data in GPU memory and i have a function bitblt that copies a rectangular array of RGB data from one image into another one.

The code worked fine on my last PC with a GTX580 with CUD3.x (can't restore any more).

Now i have a GTX680 and use CUDA 4.x.

The kernel looks like this, it worked fine on GTX580 / CUDA 3.x:

```
__global__ void cujpeg_k_bitblt(CUJPEG* dd, CUJPEG* src, int sx, int sy, int tx, int ty, int w, int h)
{
  unsigned char* sb;
  unsigned char* s;
  unsigned char* db;
  unsigned char* d;
  int tid;
  int x, y;
  int xs, ys, xt, yt;
  int ws, wt;

  sb = src->dev_rgb;
  db = dd->dev_rgb;

  ws = src->stride;
  wt = dd->stride;

  for(tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x; tid < w * h; tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
    y = tid / w;
    x = tid - y * w;

    xs = x + sx;
    ys = y + sy;

    xt = x + tx;
    yt = y + ty;

    s = sb + (ys * ws + xs) * 3;
    d = db + (yt * wt + xt) * 3;

    d[0] = s[0];
    d[1] = s[1];
    d[2] = s[2];
  }
 }
```

I wonder what this could be related to, maybe the higher numbers for several properties on the GTX680 generate an overflow somewhere?

- threads in warp 32
- max threads per block 1024
- max thread dim 1024 1024 64
- max grid dim 2147483647 65535 65535

Any hints would be really appreciated.

I develop on Linux, use OpenSuSE 12.1.

Best regards,
Torsten.

Edit, 2012-08-22:
I use:
devdriver_4.0_linux_64_270.40.run
cudatools_4.0.13_linux_64.run
cudatoolkit_4.0.13_linux_64_suse11.2.run

Regarding the timing of that function bitblt:
On my last PC with Cuda 3.x and GTX580 that function took a few milliseconds.
Now it times out after several seconds.
There are other kernels running, if i comment out the call to bitblt everything runs fine.
Also using printf() i can see that all calls before bitblt were fine and after bitblt nothing is executed.

I can't really think that that kernel itself is the problem but i don't know what can influence the behaviour i see.

Best regards,
Torsten.

Comment: Which version of CUDA 4.x? It is an important detail because the compiler for compute 2.x and 3.0 devices changed during the CUDA 4.x release cycle.

Comment: Maybe the launch is timing out because the kernel runs too long. Try disabling the watchdog timer or running on a non-display GPU and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Ok, i found the problem.  As the JPEG decoder is a library i give the user some flexibility in decoding, so when calling CUDA kernels i don't have fixed paramters for grids / threads but use pre-initialised values that i set at initialisation and that the user can overwrite.  These default values i get from the CUDA properties of the GPU used but i use not the correct values.  The grids are 2147483647, but 65535 is the maximum value allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i found the problem. As the JPEG decoder is a library i give the user some flexibility in decoding, so when calling CUDA kernels i don't have fixed paramters for grids / threads but use pre-initialised values that i set at initialisation and that the user can overwrite. These default values i get from the CUDA properties of the GPU used but i use not the correct values. The grids are 2147483647, but 65535 is the maximum value allowed.